# ListView Expanding Cells Animation Dosen't collapse

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

Hi i found this video on [devBytes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ) a nice expanding listView animation you can download the [code](http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewExpandingCells.zip).
This code works perfectly but when i try to add anything in the expanding layout like a button or a text my list view expands and shows the new elements but can never collapse.
There was no errors or exception shown in the logcat and since i'am new in android i can't realy figure out where the problem is.
After debugging my code i noticed that the expanded listview  item dosen't enter the click listner method.

This is the list_view_item.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/border"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_linear_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <com.example.android.expandingcells.ExpandingLayout
        android:id="@+id/expanding_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_expanding_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>



  </com.example.android.expandingcells.ExpandingLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What did you add? How did you add? Post some code please